# How to display json values from api page to page in next.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, next.js

I have an **api page** `secured.js` (where i elaborate user session data) and its counterpart **normal page** `secured.js` (where I show the elaborated content from the api page).

This is the api page **secured.js**:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client'

const secret = process.env.SECRET

export default async (req, res) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  const token = JSON.stringify(session.token);

  var tokenUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&mine=true&key=<key>&access_token=${token}`;
  tokenUrl = tokenUrl.replace(/"/g, '');
  const url = await fetch(tokenUrl);
  const data = await url.json();

  if (session) {
    res.send({ content: JSON.stringify(data.items) })
  } else {
    res.send({ error: 'You must be sign in to view the protected content on this page.' })
  }
}
```

this is the normal page **secured.js**:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/client'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import AccessDenied from '../components/access-denied'

export default function Page () {
  const [ session, loading ] = useSession()
  const [ content , setContent ] = useState()

  // Fetch content from protected route
  useEffect(()=>{
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await fetch('/api/examples/protected')
      const json = await res.json()
      if (json.content) { setContent(json.content) }
    }
    fetchData()
  },[session])

  // When rendering client side don't display anything until loading is complete
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && loading) return null

  // If no session exists, display access denied message
  if (!session) { return  <Layout><AccessDenied/></Layout> }

  // If session exists, display content
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Your favorite Channels</h1>
      <div>{content}</div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

The `<div>{content}</div>` inside `<Layout>` outputs the json data retrieved from the api page, how can i iterate through that data and show it for instance inside a ul `li` ?

what i've tried is changing `<div>{content}</div>` with the following:

```
<div>{content.map((id, sub) => (
        <li key={id}>
        <img class="img-rounded" src={sub.snippet.thumbnails.default.url} />
        <h4>{sub.snippet.title}</h4>
        </li>
      ))}</div>
```

but it says "content" is undefined.

the **json** looks like this doing a `console.log(data)`:

```
{
  kind: 'youtube#SubscriptionListResponse',
  etag: '9zUjByxqEbu9WrZxZ9KykymtKAQ',
  nextPageToken: 'CAUQAA',
  pageInfo: { totalResults: 14, resultsPerPage: 5 },
  items: [
    {
      kind: 'youtube#subscription',
      etag: 'N0uKZfzGEUkRStfyhc6leQJlbR4',
      id: 'I_5v-i46Mo0XuNIRp6SftSJ6E2HQ9f_2H___G6CgCbQ',
      snippet: [Object],
      contentDetails: [Object]
    },
    {
      kind: 'youtube#subscription',
      etag: 'oA4L_vI93bndMnvb9wdIcNTvRTs',
      id: 'I_5v-i46Mo0XuNIRp6SftelW2GFn1r_bjGM3stfrHHk',
      snippet: [Object],
      contentDetails: [Object]
    },
    {
      kind: 'youtube#subscription',
      etag: 'Da7_Kr-SvEM7k7ym4U2DnhYGjEI',
      id: 'I_5v-i46Mo1ASTbnb0w3KbLKuV8luK4Qu2hHRqoi9q4',
      snippet: [Object],
      contentDetails: [Object]
    },
    {
      kind: 'youtube#subscription',
      etag: '0qvi1ljHGdwce4AbtU5lr7hiV_w',
      id: 'I_5v-i46Mo2B_hsy4IR8bTAgLRZHKJWadXnNDo_9srM',
      snippet: [Object],
      contentDetails: [Object]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you log `console.log(json)` before `if (json.content) { setContent(json.content) }` in your page secured.js?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, it logs: [object Object] (in the browser console only, no log server side)

Comment: What about `console.log(json.content)`? And what is type of `console.log(typeof json.content)`?

Comment: both logs: undefined

Comment: I think you need to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(json))` to figure it out what is it.

Comment: it logs: {"content":"[{\"kind\":\"youtube#subscription\",\"etag\":\"yvR etc..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your logic for display. There will be a period where your session is defined, and your content has not been retrieved from the backend.

So there should be something like

```
  // When rendering client side don't display anything until loading is complete
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && loading) return null

  // If no session exists, display access denied message
  if (!session) { return  <Layout><AccessDenied/></Layout> }
  // now retrieving from the backend
  if (!content) { return <div>Retrieving from backend</div> }
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to work, the logic commented as you see is taken by the example repository of next-auth, in fact content as i stated returns the json data if i don't iterate through .map